# Nokogiri Tag with id and a normal field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I am trying to create a line in an xml file that looks like this `<Type id="Standard">Economy 3-5 Business Days</Type>`. So far I have only been able to make it look like `<Type id="Standard" value="Economy 3-5 Business Days"/>`.

Maybe I missed it in the [nokogiri docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Builder), but I couldn't find anyway to get the line to show up like the first example.

My like currently looks like `xml.Type(id: 'Standard', value:'Economy 3-5 Business Days')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `xml.Type('Economy 3-5 Business Days', id: 'Standard')`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the whole story about what do you expect to build in your software, but this could help you:

```
require 'nokogiri'

builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.Type.Standard! "Economy 3-5 Business Days"
end
puts builder.to_xml
```

Which outputs:

```
#> <?xml version="1.0"?>
#> <Type id="Standard">Economy 3-5 Business Days</Type>
```

Here is some documentation you should read in case you would like to build more complex documents: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Builder

Comment: I was reading those docs, I linked it in my original question but was having but I missed how to add the id to the line

Comment: Oh, sorry, missed your link. Well, let it be in mine answer too ;)